# SOAP-UI - how to externalize or encrypt passwords in a project

Tags: soapui, password-protection

I have a project with some SOAP interfaces configured to test my backends.

To be able to transfer the credentials, I had the choice either to:

1. Put a soap header `<soapenv:Header>...</soapenv:Header>` containing username and password 
    But in this case, I have to declare it in all Request and it is not dynamic as the credentials changes for the different endpoint configured (environments)
2. Create a `Outgoing WS-Security Configurations` for all my environment and associate them in the `Endpoint` configuration of each `Interface`
    That way it will switch credentials easily and automatically whatever endpoint used.
    In this configuration I can also define not to generate a `nonce`, other ways it generate it automatically and the server does not accept it.

Now I have a *little* security problem. My SOAP-UI is in a git repository and if I just open the project xml file, I can see my passwords in clear text.

I tried to use `Hashed password` but:

1. The server does not allows this: it needs the password in `PasswordText` format
2. I think the Hash is base64 encoded, then not secured

Is there any way to externalize the password (they can be stored in a local plaintext file) or to be encrypted in the project.xml file?

I am using SOAP-UI Open source version (not PRO) in version 5.2.0 and from the user interface and not with Maven or any other tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can using global properties. To do so you need first to define a external file for example a file called soapuiProperties.txt.

Inside this file put both properties:

```
myProject.username=yourUserName
myProject.password=yourPassword
```

Then configure your WS-Security configuration setting and set `${myProject.username}` as username, and `${myProject.password}` as password (you don't see the password text because the UI field has a mask but don't worry if you put correctly the property then SOAPUI replace it for the correct value in the property file anyway).

[image]

Finally you've to pass the file to the SOAPUI, so edit `SOAPUI_HOME\bin\soapui.bat` an add the follow `-Dsoapui.properties=soapuiProperties.txt` to the `JAVA_OPTS`:

`set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx256m -Dsoapui.properties=soapuiProperties.txt`

And that's all, then when you apply `WSSSettings` to your request you'll see the correct values get it from the property file.

You can see more info at SOAPUI documentation [here](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/working-with-properties.html#2-Setting-properties-from-the-command-line)

**EDIT**

In new versions at least with 5.2.1 seems easier, by default SOAPUI is configured to load `SOAPUI_HOME\bin\soapui.properties` by default. So create this file and add the properties here, You've to do the rest of the steps but you can avoid to edit the `soapui.bat`.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Perfect, I confirm in 5.2.0 the soapui.properties file is also configured by default in the launcher (mine is soapui.sh as I am under Linux).  I just need to tell my colleagues to set-up the soapui.properties file with the proper keys and it is fine.